# Ruby incorrect array management

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following piece of code:

```
nonce = data.scan(/nonce="(.*)"/)
```

`data` is a string ,the matched piece of string is assigend to nonce variable which automatically becomes an Array.
Now, if i

```
puts nonce[0]
```

I will get  my value printed correctly:

```
51d8852d
```

but if use:

```
puts "final string #{md1}:#{nonce[0]}:#{md2}"
```

the output will be:

```
df49f55acfd9d21837fd840644f251b4:["51d8852d"]:3b7718806908d2a4456086be7daba94ccd36ea19fd2bfa80ae41fa8be23433b7
```

but there shouldn't be any brackets or duoble quotes, i should get only the array's value.
It should be something like this:

```
df49f55acfd9d21837fd840644f251b4:51d8852d:3b7718806908d2a4456086be7daba94ccd36ea19fd2bfa80ae41fa8be23433b7
```

Could you please suggest me how to solve this issue?
Thanks

Dawid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use scan with a capture group, the result is an array of arrays, so you want to use `nonce[0][0]`. You got confused because your first example feeds `nonce[0]`, which is an array, to `puts`, which handles arrays by printing out each element. If you do `puts nonce[0].class`, you'll see...

Comment: Or use nonce.flatten[0]. The end result is the same so it really depends on what looks better.